# Jpa ManyToMany paginate

Tags: spring, jpa, many-to-many, jql

I have a ManyToMany relationship between `User` and `Post` entities where a User can Like multiple Posts and vis versa. Child entities are lazy loaded.

Now I want to paginate over all posts with Spring Data Jpa and show all posts in my SPA frontend where a User can Like Posts, but only if the user did not already liked that Post.

My question now is: how can I enrich my posts which are loaded via Spring repository only with a boolean flag indicating if the current user already liked that Posts, so I can disable the like button on my frontend?

Comment: Currently I'm in the phase of designing the ER Diagramm and Just thought about how I could achive this to verify my design ist correct. Searched a lot in the net, but didn't find any resource.  The only solition I cam up with is fetching all posts, iterate over them and doing a ```likes.contains(user)``` to set a transient field on the Post. But I doubt this is the optimal solution as this results in page size sub selects.

Comment: Is there a reason why you insist on performing the check in memory? The obvious solution would be to use a query (joining `User`s and `Post`s), and return a list of [`projections`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) from your repository method

Comment: I guess I was overcomplicating things. Thought there might be a solution to do everything with one query for optimal performance.. But at the end you are right, its just SQL and a ``` left outer join``` to fetch only the likes of the current user which than can be projected should do it.